# Exporting async functions with React, (getting error when running npm build)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, async-await, es6-promise

I am re-using async functions within my React project, and I have a file called `apiRequest.js` which looks like this:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const serverURL = "http://localhost:8080"

getInfo = async function ({email}) {
  try {
      return await axios.post(serverURL, { email: email })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
}

module.exports = {
    getInfo
};
```

My component attempts to load the function like this, which **works in dev mode**:

```
import { getInfo } from "./../../util/apiRequest.js";
```

When I run `npm run build`, I get this error:

`Attempted import error: 'getInfo' is not exported from './../../util/apiRequest.js'.`

What am I doing wrong when exporting this function?

I have tried removing the `const` & removing the fat arrow `=>` but still get the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the ES6 modules import and export

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export const getInfo = async() => {

}
```